# /bin/sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('

Tags: python, bash, subprocess, sh

```
arg2 = f'cat <(grep \'#\' temp2.vcf) <(sort <(grep -v \'#\' temp2.vcf) | sortBed -i - | uniq ) > out.vcf'
print(arg2)
try:
    subprocess.call(arg2,shell=True)
except Exception as error:
    print(f'{error}')
```

While I'm running this I get the following error:

```
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('   
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: `cat <(grep '#' temp2.vcf) <(sort <(grep -v '#' temp2.vcf) | sortBed -i - | uniq ) > Out.vcf'
```

but when I run in the command line it works.

Comment: Copy this into shellcheck.net and it will spit out the issues. You’ll see that your escaping of the single quote isn’t adequate.

Comment: It often helps to simplify things. Extract a [mcve], in particular. Also, please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python's `call()` function invokes the command with `sh` by default. The process substitution syntax is supported by `bash`, but not by `sh`.

```
$ sh -c "cat <(date)"  
sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
sh: -c: line 0: `cat <(date)'

$ bash -c "cat <(date)"
Mon Mar 14 11:12:48 PDT 2022
```

If you really need to use the bash-specific syntax, you should be able to specify the shell executable (but I have not tried this):

```
subprocess.call(arg2, shell=True, executable='/bin/bash')
```

Comment: I don't know about redundant; the purpose of the first `cat` seems to be to collect the `#` lines followed by the output from the pipe.

Comment: yes @tripleee is right. It captures the # and then later excludes it before sorting.
But executable='/bin/bash' worked. Thank you so much

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I have removed the part of my answer that was not relevant to the solution.

Answer (score 2):

The immediate error is that your attempt uses [Bash-specific syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725296/difference-between-sh-and-bash). You can work around that with an `executable="/bin/bash"` keyword argument; but really, why are you using a complex external pipeline here at all? Python can do all these things except `sortBed` natively.

```
with open("temp2.vcf", "r"
      ) as vcfin, open("out.vcf", "w") as vcfout:
    sub = subprocess.Popen(
        ["sortBed", "-i", "-"],
        text=True,
        stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

    for line in vcfin:
        if "#" in line:
            vcfout.write(line)
        else:
            sub.stdin.write(line)

    subout, suberr = sub.communicate()

    if suberr is not None:
        sys.stderr.write(suberr)

    seen = set()
    for line in subout.split("\n"):
        if line not in seen:
            vcfout.write(line + "\n")
        seen.add(line)
```

The Python reimplementation is slightly clunkier (and untested, as I don't have `sortBed` or your input data) but that also means it's more obvious where to change something if you want to modify it.

Comment: I would probably still use `uniq` in place of a pure Python reimplementation, something like `subprocess.run(['uniq'], stdin=sub.stdout, stdout=vcfout)`

Comment: @chepner In that case, perhaps create a single `subprocess` with a pipeline and `shell=True` and simply write into that in the first loop. I guess we can assume that the direct writes to the open file handle will arrive first, though I haven't verified that.

Comment: Update: I needed to add an explicit `vcfout.flush()` for that case, to force the stuff written to the pipe before the subprocess `communicate()` to be written out to the file first.

Comment: But I require a sorted file to be again sorted using sortbed here. executable="/bin/bash" worked. Thank you so much.